# How to use LayerManager in Java

Tags: java

I am beginner with Java. I have a question about how to create a map which has multiple layers just like flash (layer 1,layer 2, etc).

I don't have any ideas how to create layers in the map. For example, layer 1 is construct with background image, layer 2 is construct with static image icon like road, layer 3 is constructed with buildings, and etc.

Any tutorials can refer?

Any one has any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html). See [How to Use Layered Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) in the Java Tutorial for further details.

Alternately, override paintComponent(Graphics) in a [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) and simply draw the parts of each layer in order from bottom layer to top.